# Pandas "DataFrame"s as class properties. How should I initialize them in class constructor __init__()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-class

I have a class which will manage multiple pandas Data Frames. The Data frames are class properties. I have initiated every Data Frame in the class constructor and assigned an empty Data Frame to them (Because Data Frames are not available at the time of creating a class instance and some of them will be created using data from other Data Frames of this class) like this:

```
class MyClass:
    """
    Handle data cached in csv files
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """
        initialize MyClass class
        """

        self._parent_df = pd.DataFrame()
        self._child_df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.stored_data_df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.personnel_data_df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.salary_df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.settings = {}
        self._last_update = self._get_last_upd()
        self._last_events_df = pd.DataFrame()

    @property
    def parent_df(self):
        if not self._parent_df.empty
            return self._parent_df
        else:
            raise AttributeError()

    @parent_df.setter
    def parent_df(self, value: pd.DataFrame):
        self._parent_df = value

    # more properties getting and setting DataFrames
    
    # … and some methods working with data in multiple DataFrames
```

What is the best practice to write this class? Since Initializing and assigning Data Frames are resource heavy tasks, is this approach considered 'Pythonic'? Should I avoid defining them in **init** or assign 'None' as initial value instead of empty Data Frames?
`self._parent_df = None`
Also, if anybody knows any good open source package that has a class working like this, I'll be Happy to look at.

Comment: It is better to provide them as arguments to the constructor, IMO, fully formed

Comment: How many of these objects are you going to create?  If you need 5 dataframes, then that's what you have to do.  Creating an empty dataframe is not that expensive.  It's much cheaper than importing pandas, for example.  But couldn't some of these be simple dictionaries?  Why pandas?

Comment: I'll note, using property this way makes little sense. you might as well leave the attributes not initialized. But again, I would just rethink the design of your class

Comment: Some of the class properties are not available at the time of creating class instances. so they can't be constructor args. They will be created using other properties. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: About 10. They can't be dictionaries. The smallest one contains 4000+ rows and I need to do mathmatical operations on them. @TimRoberts

Comment: I also think my class needs redesign but I don't have an alternative design to replace. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Why do you need to initialize them with empty dataframes? The setter replaces the value, it doesn't update the df. So initialize them with `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I believe this approach is quite expensive Since, with the initialization of the object, you are doing expensive initialization (plenty of data frames, etc.).

The best approach is called lazy initialization, in which the getter of a property is responsible for initializing the property itself (in case it wasn't initialized).
Sample Code:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = None

    @property
    def value(self):
        if self._value is None:
            self._value = expensive_initialization()
        return self._value

my_instance = MyClass()
```

When we access `my_instance.value` for the first time, the `my_instance._value`will trigger the call for the expensive_inistialization (whatever it is for that property).
This way, you trigger the initialization for each property on its first-time need.

for packages, there is [lazy_python](https://pypi.org/project/lazy_python/), for further explanation you have this nice article for someone who went deep into explaining this approach.
[How to Create Lazy Attributes to Improve Performance in Python.](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-create-lazy-attributes-to-improve-performance-in-python-b369fd72e1b6).

I hope this helps!